# Python built-in functions for class object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to python. I've heard that everything is an object when it comes to python even if class or function.

As far as I know, the class object is created when the program starts. So  I wonder if there's some function for initializing class variables or doing something.

**init** function can't do because its parameter is self which's for an instance of the class. I want to access the class itself.

```py
class Example():

    def __init__(self):
# I know that this function is called when an instance of this class is created
        pass


    def __something__(cls):
# Is there some function for initializing class object?
# What I wanna do is I want to initialize class variables or call some functions...
# But __init__ function can't do because its parameter is self.
        pass
```

Comment: Just do `cls_attr = 'Foo'` inside the `class` definition…!?

Comment: yes, you are looking for a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the class object is created at run time as Python is a [Dynamic Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Dynamic_programming_language).

So if you want to initiate class variables you could just set them right after class definition

```
class Cls:
  cls_var = "before"

print(Cls.cls_var)
Cls.cls_var = "after"
print(Cls.cls_var)
```

this would print "before" and "after"

Answer (score -1):

you can operate the class you defined directly.

for example, your class name is Example, you can use buildin method dir to see the class method (`dir(Example)`), use type to see the class type (`type(Example)`), `__dict__` see the class attributes(`Example.__dict__`) ...